# How to build projects from network shares with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, network-drive

I have a virtual machine with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010, and I want to be able to build  C++ projects from a network drive.

I tried to use a shared folder from VirtualBox or a folder shared via samba from OS X.

None of the solutions worked.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Just don't do it. Even if you mapped it as a folder the speed (especially when compiling, which intellisense does a lot in VC2010) is very bad. It took me about 5x the compilation time of a local copy.

Comment: Can you access the files/folders from Windows Explorer? If yes, can you access the same from VS? Did you need to give username/password?

Comment: @RedX: It may be reasonable if you enable CSC (Client Side Caching, aka Offline Files).

Answer (score 1):

Have you mapped a network drive in Windows, or are you just opening a network location and trying to build? The latter VS doesn't like, the former should work.